# Assigned variable has empty output from nslookup and ping commands

Tags: shell, variable, output

I am trying to assign an resolved IP address to variable:

```
ip=$(ping -q -c1 -W1 google.com | grep -Eo "([0-9]+\.?){4}" | head -n 1) | echo $ip
```

or

```
ip=`resolveip google.com | head -n 1` | echo $ip
```

Both echo returns empty output. Without assigning it to variables commands works good. What i am doing wrong?

Comment: I may suggest using `dig -t AAAA +short google.com` or `dig -t A +short google.com` directly returning the IPv6 or IPv4 address, respectively. No need to sieve it out with special `head` or `grep` commands like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to achieve seems to be outputting the content of the shell variable `$ip` after assigning the output of the `ping` command to it - that means, you want to *first* assign command output to a variable, and *then* print the resulting variable content on the console.

However, you are using the pipe (`|`) operator to link these two commands. This is the wrong operator for two reasons.

- First, that operator is used to redirect the output of a command to the input of another; however a variable assignment doesn't produce output, and the `echo` command doesn't read from `stdin`. While that isn't the root cause of your problem, you may run into problems in more complex situations when using the `|` operator in that non-intended way.
- More seriously (and likely the actual reason for the observed behavior), the commands on both ends of such a pipeline are started simultaneously so that the receiving command can process the output from the sending command "as it comes" (in particular, without needing to buffer the entire output). In your case, this means that the `echo $ip` command is executed immediately, and likely before the shell had time to fill it with the output from `ping`.

So, the solution for both issues is to use the `;` instead for simple sequential execution of two commands that only happen to be written on the same line:

```
ip=$(ping -q -c1 -W1 google.com | grep -Eo "([0-9]+\.?){4}" | head -n 1) ; echo $ip
```